# FLEX Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, asynctoken

I’m getting the error “[RPC Fault faultString="Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds." faultCode="EncodingError" faultDetail="null"]:” when uploading a bytearray trough a web service.

Now…this occurs only when the bytearray size is higher than 50 mb…aprox.

Here is the line of code that gives the error where pFileData is the byteArray I’m sending.

```
        pFileData.position = 0;
        pFileData.compress();           
        var call:AsyncToken = service.UploadAttachmentBytes(pFileData);
```

Thanks.

TimeLimit for the script is 60 seconds by default.

Comment: How are you uploading?  What Flex Component are you using?  Is there any reason why you can't change the timeout variable on that service?

Comment: I'm using cairngorm model in this case UploadAttachmentBytes is the C# webservice. I'm using event/command/delegate model. about the timeout on the service...can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is when you do `pfileData.compress()` on a 50+ MB file. Compressing the larger file takes time, and web browsers will generate a similar error message if any code (Javascript or Actionscript) executes for longer than 15 seconds. I'm guessing this has nothing to do w/uploading, and that you might want to look at Actionscript workers to compress/upload in a different thread.

Comment: Thank you Sunil, but actually the line of code that hangs the app is var call:AsyncToken = service.UploadAttachmentBytes(pFileData);  not sure how to work around this issue...